# FSharpChoice in C#

Tags: c#, f#

I am trying to use `FSharpChoice` type in a C# project. I have created a choice like so

```
var a = FSharpChoice<T1,T2,T3>.NewChoice1Of3(instofT1);
```

now how do I get `instofT1` out of the choice type.

I see I can do a `IsChoice1Of3` but how do i get to the value in the choice object?

Comment: Also see [discriminated-union-in-c-sharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151702/discriminated-union-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast the value to `FSharpChoice<T1,T2,T3>.Choice1Of3` and use the `Item` property.

See [Compiled Form of Union Types for Use from Other CLI Languages](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597545) ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20110401234450/http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597545), [latest](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/)) in the F# spec for more information about how discriminated unions are represented.

Answer (score 6):

I probably wouldn't use the type directly from C# - you can do that, but the resulting code won't be very nice. I'd probably declare my own `Choice` type that would look like this:

```
type Choice<'T1, 'T2> private (opt1, opt2) =
  member x.TryGetChoice1Of2(arg:byref<'T1>) = //'
    match opt1 with
    | Some v -> arg <- v; true
    | _ -> false
  // Similar code for 'TryGetChoice2Of2'

type Choice = // static methods for creating (Choice1Of2, ...)
```

This uses `byref` parameters which appear as `out` parameters in C#, so you could write:

```
int num;
string str;
if (choice.TryGetChoice1Of2(out num)) // ...
else if (choice.TryGetChoice2Of2(out str)) // ...
else // assert(false)
```

This is definitely more pleasant way of working with the type from C# (and it uses pattern familiar from, for example, working with `Int32.TryParse`).

Comment: I like this approach, but I like Juliet's approach in this other answer even better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151702/discriminated-union-in-c/3199453#3199453.

Comment: Which I'd translate as `type IChoice<'a,'b,'c> = abstract Match : Func<'a, 't> * Func<'b, 't> * Func<'c, 't> -> 't` in F#.

Comment: @kvb: Yes, that looks very nice too. (I'd say nicer & more functional, but a bit less csharpish :-))

Answer (score 3):

[I recently started a project](https://github.com/mausch/FSharp.Core.CS) to make a "compatibility layer" so that FSharp.Core can be more easily consumed from C#. In particular, it makes generic discriminated unions usable from C#, for example:

```
var choice = Choice.New1Of3<int,string,string>(100);
int r = choice.Match(i => i + 21, s => s.Length + 1, s => s.Length + 5);
```

This does pattern matching on the discriminated union, similarly to how you would do it in F#, except there are no names.