# Unable to cast an F# Object in C#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

Given this F#:

```
namespace DU_Sample  

type StateA = { Counter: int }  
type StateB = { Counter: int; Pass: bool }  

type DU =  
| A of StateA  
| B of StateB
```

And this C#:

```cs
[TestMethod]  
public void TestMethod1()  
{  
  var stateB = GetStateB();  
  Assert.IsTrue( stateB.IsB );  
  //Assert.IsTrue( ((DU_Sample.StateB)stateB).Pass );  // nope  
  //var nutherB = DU_Sample.DU.NewB( stateB );  // nope  
  Assert.IsTrue( ( (dynamic)stateB ).Item.Pass );  // pass  
}  

private static DU_Sample.DU GetStateB()  
{  
  var stateB = new DU_Sample.StateB( 0, true );  
  return DU_Sample.DU.NewB( stateB );  
}
```

How can I cast the Discriminated Union type to one of it's parts in order to access that part's properties?

Comment: Why is `GetStateB` returning something other than a `StateB` instance? How confusing..

Comment: I think you need to cast the `stateB.Item` property.

Comment: Have you tried casting to `DU_Sample.DU.B`?

Comment: What if you wrote unit tests for F# code, in F#?

Comment: You should consider the answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254855/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-access-data-of-an-f-discriminated-union-type-in-c

Comment: @ildjarn - this is a simplified example; I want to pass the "parent" DU type around but be able to cast...

Comment: @JeffMercado - You can't access the .Item either - I only see it while debugging.

Comment: @JoelMueller - because I'd like to try to introduce F# into a C# code base if possible.  We're never going to just cut over.  This is just a sample.

Comment: @dudeNumber4 : The "parent" DU type is `DU_Sample.DU`, but `GetStateB` by its name should return a `DU_Sample.StateB`.

Comment: @ildjarn - True.  Again, contrived sample.  Just trying to isolate the particular problem I was experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases you have to (down) cast and then use the property `Item`:

```
Assert.IsTrue((stateB as DU_Sample.DU.B)?.Item.Pass ?? false); 
var nutherB = DU_Sample.DU.NewB(((DU_Sample.DU.B)stateB).Item)
```