# F# Discriminated Union usage from C#

Tags: c#, f#, c#-to-f#

What are the best ways to use F# Discriminated Unions from C#?

I have been digging into this problem for a while, I have probably found the simplest way, but as it is rather complex, there may be some other thing I don't see...

Having a discriminated union, e.g.:

```ml
type Shape =
    | Rectangle of float * float
    | Circle of float
```

the usage from C# I found would be (avoiding using vars, to make the type obvious):

```
Shape circle = Shape.NewCircle(5.0);
if (circle.IsCircle)
{
    Shape.Circle c = (Shape.Circle)circle;
    double radius = c.Item;
}
```

In C#, the `NewXXXX` static methods always create object of the `Shape` class, there is also a method `IsXXXX` to check if the object is of the type; if and only if yes, it is castable to the `Shape.XXXX` class, and only then its items are accessible; constructor of the `Shape.XXXX` classes are internal, i.e. unaccessible.

Is anyone aware of a simpler option to get the data from a discriminated union?

Comment: Must you use the discriminated union? All of the F#/C# interop code bases I have seen expose typed factories around this sort of thing to make it nicer. AFAIK there is no simpler way.

Comment: Duplicate of [What is the simplest way to access data of an F# discriminated union type in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254855/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-access-data-of-an-f-discriminated-union-type-in-c) and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090770/fsharpchoice-in-c-sharp

Comment: Concrete example: https://github.com/mausch/EdmundsNet/blob/b5ca7a7d7a883f4f0b2f7f7a7af032534e792cdb/EdmundsNet/Vehicles.fs#L119-L129

Comment: For now I will stick with `dynamic` in C#. `dynamic circle = ...; double radius = circle.Item;`

Comment: @nawfal using `dynamic` here will prevent you from doing static analysis on the types (one of the main benefits of discriminated unions)

Comment: @MauricioScheffer yes. Given the limitation today it was an easy alternative I suggested.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are writing a library in F# that is exposed to C# developers, then C# developers should be able to use it without knowing anything about F# (and without knowing that it was written in F#). This is also recommended by [F# design guidelines](http://fsharp.org/specs/component-design-guidelines/).

For discriminated unions, this is tricky, because they follow different design principles than C#. So, I would probably hide all processing functionality (like calculating area) in the F# code and expose it as ordinary members.

If you really need to expose the two cases to C# developers, then I think something like this is a decent option for a simple discriminated union:

```
type Shape =
    | Rectangle of float * float
    | Circle of float
    member x.TryRectangle(width:float byref, height:float byref) =
      match x with
      | Rectangle(w, h) -> width <- w; height <- h; true
      | _ -> false
    member x.TryCircle(radius:float byref) =
      match x with
      | Circle(r) -> radius <- r; true
      | _ -> false
```

In C#, you can use it in the same way as the familiar `TryParse` methods:

```
int w, h, r;
if (shape.TryRectangle(out w, out h)) { 
  // Code for rectangle
} else if (shape.TryCircle(out r)) {
  // Code for circle
}
```

Comment: Why do you always recommend non-exhaustive matching, when it's very easy to do it exhaustive?

Comment: Mainly because the approach above is easy to use and follows standard coding style that people in C# know already (e.g. it is quite common to use `TryParse` functions and it does not require you to put all your code inside lambda - most C# uses of lambda functions are fairly small-scope IMO).

Comment: Would you please at the very least mention the word "totality" in these answers, so that people have something to look up to properly evaluate this? Please at least consider including objective terms (e.g. totality) in addition to subjective/fuzzy ones (e.g. familiarity/idiomatic). I've wasted countless hours in my career because I didn't know these things. I wouldn't like other people to go through the same pain.

Answer (score 7):

According to the F# spec, the only interop available is through the following instance methods

- `.IsC...`
- `.Tag` (which gives an integer tag to each case)
- `.Item` (on the subtypes to get the data - this is only present when there is more than one union case)

However, you are free to write methods in the F# to make the interop easier.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that we need to calculate the *area* of each Shape polymorphically.

In C# we would normally create a hypothetical object hierarchy and a [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). In this example, we would have to create a *ShapeVisitor* class and then a derived *ShapeAreaCalculator* visitor class.

In F#, we can use Pattern Matching on the `Shape` type:

```
let rectangle = Rectangle(1.3, 10.0)
let circle = Circle (1.0)

let calculateArea shape =
    match shape with
    | Circle radius -> 3.141592654 * radius * radius
    | Rectangle (height, width) -> height * width

let rectangleArea = calculateArea(rectangle)
// -> 1.3 * 10.0

let circleArea = calculateArea(circle)
// -> 3.141592654 * 1.0 * 1.0
```