# Working with F# types in C#

Tags: c#, types, f#

I have a C# web api which I use to access an F# library. I have created a DU of the types I want to return and use pattern matching to choose which is return back to the c# controller.

In the C# controller how do I access the data of the type which is return from the function call to the F# library?

C# Controller

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post()
{
    var _result = Authentication.GetAuthBehaviour();
    //Access item1 of my tuple
    var _HTTPStatusCode = (HttpStatusCode)_result.item1;
    //Access item2 of my tuple
    var _body = (HttpStatusCode)_result.item2;
    return base.Request.CreateResponse(_HTTPStatusCode, _body);
}
```

F# Types

```
module Types =
    [<JsonObject(MemberSerialization=MemberSerialization.OptOut)>]
    [<CLIMutable>]
    type ValidResponse = {
         odata: string;
         token: string; 
    }

    [<JsonObject(MemberSerialization=MemberSerialization.OptOut)>]
    [<CLIMutable>]
    type ErrorResponse = {
         code: string;
         message: string;
         url: string; 
    }

    type AuthenticationResponse = 
    | Valid of int * ValidResponse
    | Error of int * ErrorResponse
```

F# function

```
module Authentication = 
    open Newtonsoft.Json

    let GetAuthBehaviour () =
        let behaviour = GetBehaviour.Value.authentication
        match behaviour.statusCode with
        | 200 ->
            let deserializedAuthenticationResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Types.ValidResponse>(behaviour.body)
            Types.Valid (behaviour.statusCode, deserializedAuthenticationResponse)
        | _ ->
            let deserializedAuthenticationResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Types.ErrorResponse>(behaviour.body)
            Types.Error (behaviour.statusCode, deserializedAuthenticationResponse)
```

Comment: There is an example how to deal with discriminated unions in C# here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23843142/f-discriminated-union-usage-from-c-sharp . It also suggests that according to F# design guidelines you should perhaps consider hiding the discriminated union from the API available in C#. The F# tuples will be automatically converted to instances of the appropriate `Tuple<>` type, so you could easily just return a 3-tuple from the F# code and have a lot less headache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

F# Discriminated Unions are compiled as abstract classes, with each case being a derived nested class. From C#, you can access the cases by attempting to downcast the result from `GetAuthBehaviour`:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post()
{
    var result = Authentication.GetAuthBehaviour();

    var valid = result as Types.AuthenticationResponse.Valid;
    if (valid != null)
    {
        int statusCode = valid.Item1;
        Types.ValidResponse body = valid.Item2;
        return this.CreateResponse(statusCode, body);
    }

    var error = result as Types.AuthenticationResponse.Error;
    if (error != null)
    {
        int statusCode = error.Item1;
        Types.ErrorResponse body = error.Item2;
        return this.CreateResponse(statusCode, body);
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException("...");
}
```

Notice that the C# compiler doesn't know that you've handled all the cases, so you'll need to supply a branch that handles the case where `result` is neither `Valid` nor `Error`. Here, I've simply thrown an exception as an example, but in a Web API, it'd probably be more appropriate to return a `500` status code.

All that said, though, why even have the trouble of writing and maintaining the Controllers in C#? You can [write an ASP.NET Web API purely in F#](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/08/23/how-to-create-a-pure-f-aspnet-web-api-project).