# Is it possible to make a list of generics that return a specific data type?

Tags: c#, inheritance

```
class a {

}

class b<T>:a {
 public T foo;
}


List<a> foo2 = new List<a>();

b<int> foo3 = new b<int>();

foo3.foo = 4;

foo2.add(foo3);
```

now foo2[0].foo won't work since class a does not have that property. However I want to make it so the list can have a bunch of generic items.

Currently I am converting all the type to strings or a byte array. Is there a way to create a list of generic items that will return a specific type back?

Comment: What do you have in mind exactly? "Return a specific type" is a bit unclear. Also, even if `foo2[0].foo` worked in the general case you still have a problem: how do you know that `foo2[0]` actually has a `foo`? It might be just an `a` instance. If it could never be an `a` instance then why is the list a list of `a`?

Comment: For example suppose there were two items on the list b<int> and b<float> then foo2[0].foo would return an int and foo2[1].foo would return a float.

Comment: This is pretty unclear. Could you please make it more clear about what you're asking?

Comment: @SamFisher83: I am asking that not because *I* need to know but in order to help you think properly about it. And what would you do with the int and the float, or the string, or the whatever? You don't know their type because `foo2[0]` could be anything.

Comment: In my case the classes also have a type tag associated with them. So currently I am just returning a string which is just re-parsed. I was trying to get rid of the parsing step, but maybe it isn't possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a solution without type casts, you should take a look at the accepted answer to this question: [Discriminated union in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151702/discriminated-union-in-c-sharp)

The Union3 (or 4 or 5 or how many different types you need) type proposed by Juliet would allow you to have a list that accepts only the types you want:

```
    var l = new List<Union3<string, DateTime, int>>  {
            new Union3<string, DateTime, int>(DateTime.Now),
            new Union3<string, DateTime, int>(42),
            new Union3<string, DateTime, int>("test"),
            new Union3<string, DateTime, int>("one more test")
    };

        foreach (Union3<string, DateTime, int> union in l)
        {
            string value = union.Match(
                str => str,
                dt => dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                i => i.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine("Matched union with value '{0}'", value);
        }
```

See here for complete example: http://ideone.com/WZqhIb