# How to write a method that may return two different kinds of types?

Tags: c#, .net, methods, return, boxing

I have a class named Vector, to which I'm implementing the multiplication operator, here's my implementation :

```
public static Object operator *(Vector x, Vector y)
{

    //Possible return objects
    Matrix multiplicationResultMatrix;
    float multiplicationResultScalar = 0f;


    if (x.VectorType != y.VectorType)
    {
        if (x.Length == y.Length)
        {
            if ((x.VectorType == VectorType.Row) && (y.VectorType == VectorType.Column))
            {
                for (ulong i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
                {
                    multiplicationResultScalar += x[i] * y[i];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if ((x.VectorType == VectorType.Column) && (y.VectorType == VectorType.Row))
                {
                    multiplicationResultMatrix = new Matrix(x.Length);
                    for (ulong j = 0; j < x.Length; j++)
                    {
                        for (ulong i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
                        {
                            multiplicationResultMatrix[i, j] += x[i] * y[j];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArithmeticException("Unhandled Arithmetic Exception, Multiplication of two vectors of different length is not allowed");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArithmeticException("Unhandled Arithmetic Exception, Multiplicating vectors of the same type is not allowed");
    }

    //What should I return
    return ?
}
```

How should I define the return type ? I thought about boxing them, and unboxing when consuming them, but I don't think it's a good safe solution.

**Update :**

I have thought also about just returning a matrix object, since the scalar is a 1x1 matrix, the problem is that the matrix class got some complexe methods and properies that wouldn't just work fine in the case of 1x1 (that would force me to add some code), plus I want to minimize and optimize calculations, I'm handling matrices multiplications of the range of millions.

Comment: For this code, you should define the return type as `Matrix` and completely forget about the scalar result branch. The caller can inspect the result (which it would have to do no matter what you chose), see that it's 1x1 and extract the scalar value.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it probably belongs to Code Review.

Comment: I 'm going into guesswork here, but: 1) If the `Matrix` class won't work correctly with a 1x1 matrix then simply put the class has at least one bug that should be fixed, period. Saying that you would have to *add* code is also kind of a red flag, because usually it's exactly "additional" code that causes these problems and the solution is to *remove* it. 2) "minimize and optimize calculations" is too generic to be useful.

Comment: @Jon : Thx for the explanation, I'll take your advice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should refrain from changing the return type based on the values of the input parameters (as opposed to, say, a static type known at compile time). This makes the caller do part of your method's job, i.e figuring out what has been returned.

There are two solutions to this:

- **Always return an object of the same type** - Your method would return either an NxN matrix, or a 1x1 matrix, depending on whether the column or the row comes first, or
- **Define separate methods with different types** - Instead of using the operator, make `MultiplyRowCol` and `MultiplyColRow` methods, returning objects of different kinds.

Technically speaking, the first solution is better, because a multiplication of a row by column produces a matrix with a single element, not a scalar.

Answer (score 3):

C# has very limited support for sum types, but it is possible. There's a [nice implementation of a Discriminated Union here on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3199453/154766). Using this, your method could look like:

```
public static Union2<Matrix, float> operator *(Vector x, Vector y)
{
    (...)
    return multiplicationResultMatrix != null 
        ? new Union2<Matrix, float>.Case1(multiplicationResultMatrix)
        : new Union2<Matrix, float>.Case2(multiplicationResultFloat);
}
```

Note that I don't actually recommend doing this in this case, as I agree with other posters that it would be better design to always return a Matrix. But just so you know, it is feasible.

Answer (score 0):

If they don't have a common base class or interface then `Object` is your only choice.

Comment: + 1 This is how I do it. Just make sure to use introspection to check the type when you get it back :)

Comment: It's also useless to return `object` in this case. If you are going to force the caller to inspect the result anyway, why bother returning different types? I didn't downvote, but only marginally.

Comment: Well, yes...  But if you really want to return 2 different types of objects that don't have a common base class or interface then there is no other way to do it.  If that isn't an option then you will have to come up with a different pattern that doesn't return different types.

Comment: @BradleyUffner: So "return `object`" is an answer that is technically correct. But it's bad correct answer because the only problem it solves is the easy one ("the compiler won't let me!") and it leaves the caller to deal with the hard one ("how do I make this method most useful?").