# How can I create an abstract base class with a generic that can handle either an integer or string value?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I'm learning C# currently and have a situation where I would like to have a base abstract class that other classes will inherit from.

My challenge is that I would like to pass in either an integer or a string value depending on the situation.

Currently, I can do that with a generic IF I don't constrain the generic.  However, I think that might be a bad practice to not constrain a generic? And if it is a bad practice, how would I constrain the generic so that I'm only taking an integer or string.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
/*
I want to have a base abstract class that can handle
both an integer value and a string value
*/
public abstract class Characteristic<T> where T : int, string {
    private T _value;

    public T Value {
        get { return _value;}
        set { _value = value;}
    }
}

public class NumericAttribute : Characteristic<int> {
    private int _modifiedValue = Value + 1;
}

public class StringAttribute : Characteristic<string> {
    private string _modifiedValue = Value + " more text.";
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you need the constraint at all? The `Characteristic<T>` base class never manipulates `Value` and the subclasses know the concrete type they're dealing with so can perform the operation.

Comment: It sounds like you might be trying to create a discriminated union; which doesn't exist in C# natively. Here's example of how to create one:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3199453/7495

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *possible* to more-or-less do what you're asking; but as others have already indicated, you might not *want* to do that (and might not even *need* the constraint).  However, as I indicated in a comment, you make an interface

```
public interface IModifiable<T>
{
    T Modify(T value);
}
```

and then your own wrapper classes for `int` and `string` which implement this interface:

```
public struct Int32 : IModifiable<Int32>
{
    public System.Int32 Value { get; set; }

    public Int32 Modify(Int32 value)
    {
        return new Int32() { Value = Value + value.Value };
    }
}

public class String : IModifiable<String>
{
    public System.String Value { get; set; }

    public String Modify(String value)
    {
        return new String() { Value = Value + value.Value };
    }
}
```

Your base class now has a constraint of your interface

```
public abstract class Characteristic<T> where T : IModifiable<T>
{
    private T _value;

    public T Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; }
    }
}
```

and your derived classes, pretty much as before

```
public class NumericAttribute : Characteristic<Int32>
{
    void f()
    {
        var _modifiedValue = Value.Modify(new Int32() { Value = 1 });
    }
}

public class StringAttribute : Characteristic<String>
{
    void f()
    {
        var _modifiedValue = Value.Modify(new String() { Value = " more text." });
    }
}
```

Again, while this gives you a "solution" to your specific question, you might consider the wisdom of this approach.

Answer (score 3):

Limiting a generic class to just `int` and `string` is not possible.

- there is no "just these classes" constraint
- `int` and `string` do not share any common base class or interface that are unique to them
- `int` is a `struct` and `string` is a `class` - so even narrowing choices by `struct`/`class` constraint is not possible.

So basically generic without type constraints (with possibly checking types at run-time if it is really required) is the best generic type you can get with those 2 types. There is nothing particularly wrong with generics that don't constraint they type arguments (i.e. `List<T>`).

If you want to narrow types at least a bit `int` and `string` do have some shared interfaces - `IComparable`, `IConvertible` (non-generic once), but these interfaces are implemented by all numeric types for example.

Note: there are similar questions trying to limit generics to "numerical types" that may give some alternative approaches (including code generation). I.e. [Is there a constraint that restricts my generic method to numeric types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664/is-there-a-constraint-that-restricts-my-generic-method-to-numeric-types)