# C# type safe union

Tags: c#, variant

In C#, is there a type that can hold one of multiple types? I think this is called *typesafe union*. I am looking for a C# type that is similar to the C++ type `std::variant`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151702/discriminated-union-in-c-sharp