# Casting return type as class field

Tags: c#, .net, casting, encapsulation

I have a class that contains two fields, like the following code:

```
   public class CoffeOrText
    {
        public IEnumerable<CoffeObj> CoffeList;
        public string Text;
    }
```

Now, I want to create a new method in another file that return type is `CoffeOrTest` class like the following:

```
  public CoffeOrText GetResult()
  {
    
  }
```

What I really want to return is the filed in this class like the following(expected result):

```
  public CoffeOrText GetResult()
  {
    return result.ToList();
  }
```

which is the field in class `CoffeOrText`, how can I do that without changing the return type of method `GetResult()`

Comment: Why not construct that return type?

Comment: Why do you want for return type to be `CoffeOrTest` when you actually want to return a `List`?

Comment: Do you mean "return type is `CoffeOrText` " instead of "return type is `CoffeOrTest`"?

Comment: The reason that I can't have return type as a List or IEnumerable with method `GetResult()` is the same return type need to return a string in certain occasions. that's why I was thinking if I can do it in this way

Comment: When you want to return a list, then return a list. If you want to return a single item, then do that. And avoid one thing to be interpreted as two different things. Or in other words: your class should have exactly one responsibility, not two.

Comment: Do you want a [Discriminated Union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151702/discriminated-union-in-c-sharp)?

Comment: @Blacktea Ah, I guess that this is why `CoffeOrText` class has properties of type `IEnumerable` and `string`. Well, you could return an object of the class so in your example you would return `new CoffeOrText { CoffeList = result.ToList() }`.

Comment: @RandomSlav Thank you,  so far so good, I am so happy that there is no compiling error right now